# Работа с клавиатурой в Win Api

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как через Win Api проверить состояние клавиши: зажата, нажата, отпущена? События использовать для этой цели не могу. Только функции. Проверку зажатой клавиши уже реализовал:

```
bool result;
result=false;
if(GetAsyncKeyState(MapVirtualKey(code,MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK))==-32767) result=true;
return result;
```

Как реализовать две оставшиеся проверки?

Answer (score 4):

Используйте более простой вызов [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx), чтобы получить состояние клавиши по ее virtual-key code:

- **старший бит** возвращаемого SHORT равен 1, если клавиша **нажата**, иначе - отпущена
- **младший бит** возвращаемого SHORT равен 1, если клавиша **зажата** (toggled), иначе -
  отжата (untoggled) [актуально для клавиш типа CAPS LOCK].

Пример:

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_LEFT) < 0) {
  //  VK_LEFT нажата
} else {
  //  VK_LEFT отпущена
}

if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) % 2) == 1) {
  //  CAPS LOCK зажат
} else {
  //  CAPS LOCK отжат
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Евгений получилось?

Comment: Увы, но не получилось.

Comment: Пример рабочий, что не получилось?

Comment: Аналогично примеру не ловит клавиши совсем

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, код к вопросу, достаточный для воспроизведения Вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Частично решил проблему другим путем: через сообщения WM_KEYDOWN и WM_KEYUP.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]