# GetKeyboardState: определение состояния клавиши

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, клавиатура

Не могу понять как работает функция `GetKeyboardState`. Вроде как должна определять состояние всех клавиш, но правильность результата зависит от места вызова... Если, например, скрыть окно, либо запускать функцию по таймеру, все значения окажутся равными 0. Если же назначить некоторой кнопке обработчик и при нажатии определять состояние, скажем, LeftShift, функция покажет верное значение.

Ещё мне не ясно как обозначаются состояния клавиш. Понятно, что старший бит говорит о том нажата клавиша или нет, а вот младший - is key toggled. Что ещё за Toggled state?

**UPD:** Так же, на счёт toggled state, согласно моим наблюдениям вполне возможна ситуация когда клавиша не нажата, а старший бит равен 1 (младший 0). Не могу понять никак как это должно работать...

```
var keyboardState = new byte[256];
GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
var keyStateBits = new System.Collections.BitArray(new byte[] { keyboardState[(uint)Keys.LShiftKey] });
Debug.WriteLine("SHIFT key state: down - " + keyStateBits[0] + "; toggled - " + keyStateBits[7]);
```

**UPD2:** В самом деле мне нужно сделать работоспособным этот код:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int ToUnicodeEx(
        uint wVirtKey, 
        uint wScanCode, 
        byte[] lpKeyState, 
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszBuff, 
        int cchBuff, 
        uint wFlags, 
        IntPtr dwhkl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint MapVirtualKey(
        uint uCode, 
        uint uMapType);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

    public static string VKCodeToUnicode(uint vkCode) {

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] keyboardState = new byte[255];
        if (!GetKeyboardState(keyboardState)) return string.Empty;

        ToUnicodeEx(vkCode, MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0), keyboardState, buf, 5, 0, GetKeyboardLayout(0));
        return buf.ToString();
    }
```

Если окно отображается и активно, всё работает. Но если окно скрыть (ну через ShowWindow SW_HIDE), код выдаёт неправильные значения (без учёта состояния клавиш клавиатуры управляющих регистром и текущего языка раскладки)... Как это решить?

Comment: "Что ещё за Toggled state?"
 --
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687290/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-win-api/687611#687611 ну или подробнее на techopedia: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5327/toggle-key

Comment: Ну я так и предполагал. Для таких клавиш как Caps Look, Num Look... Но проблема вопроса в том, что это состояние так же бывает и у других клавиш. Я пробовал нажимать на Shift и значение состояния toggled непонятно для меня менялось то в 0, то в 1. От чего это зависит? И при этом значение старшего бита могло быть 0 даже если клавиша нажата.

Comment: Да и вообще, меня больше волнует вопрос на счёт `GetKeyboardState`.

Comment: @mega Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

`GetKeyboardState` работает только в случаях, когда сообщение о нажатии клавиши дошло до очереди вашего процесса (т.е., когда ваше окно в фокусе). Для получения состояния клавиши напрямую используется функция [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx). Она не работает для переключаемых клавиш типа Caps Lock - для них нужно использовать `GetKeyState` (или, в C# `Control.IsKeyLocked`, который ее использует).

```cpp
if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) != 0){
    //нажата клавиша control
}
```

Если нужно в течение длительного времени отслеживать нажатие каких-то клавиш, лучше использовать Keyboard Hook.

Toggled state - состояние Вкл/Выкл для клавиш типа Caps Lock. Для всех остальных клавиш его значение не определено.

C вызовом `GetKeyboardLayout(0)` похожая проблема - он возвращает раскладку для текущего потока, которая может не соответствовать реальной системной раскладке, если окно свернуто. Надо найти поток текущего активного окна, и брать его раскладку.

---

Итоговый пример кода (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Keyboard
{
    public const uint VK_CAPITAL = 0x14;

    [DllImport("USER32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetKeyState(int vKey);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ToUnicodeEx(
        uint wVirtKey,
        uint wScanCode,
        byte[] lpKeyState,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszBuff,
        int cchBuff,
        uint wFlags,
        IntPtr dwhkl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(
        uint uCode,
        uint uMapType);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    public static string VKCodeToUnicode(uint vkCode)
    {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] keyboardState = new byte[255];            

        short x;
        byte y;            

        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {                
            if (i == VK_CAPITAL)
            {
                x = GetKeyState(i);                                          
            }
            else
            {
                x = GetAsyncKeyState(i);                    
            }
            y = 0;
            if ((x & 0x8000) != 0) y = (byte)(y | 0x80);
            if ((x & 0x0001) != 0) y = (byte)(y | 0x01);
            keyboardState[i] = y;
        }
        
        ToUnicodeEx(vkCode, MapVirtualKey(vkCode, 0), keyboardState, buf, 5, 0, 
            GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero)));
        return buf.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Я изменил код вот так: https://pastebin.com/N0AAwjXN. Как вы понимаете, главной задачей является не определить нажата ли та или иная клавиша или нет, а получить верный Unicode символ учитывая раскладку и состояния клавиш на клавиатуре (что и запрашивает `ToUnicodeEx`).

Comment: Так вот. Замена `GetKeyboardState` на заполнение через `GetAsyncKeyState` мне не помогла. Не работает корректно. Ни регистр, не язык не учитывается.

Comment: Попробуйте лучше скопировать весь мой код в проект WinForms и сами поймёте что идёт не так... Вот вызов: https://pastebin.com/HAM2AUH7.

Comment: _Toggled state - состояние Вкл/Выкл для клавиш типа Caps Lock. Для всех остальных клавиш его значение не определено._ - Хм... Как же вы тогда объясните мои наблюдения на счёт нажатия клавиши Shift где её toggled state менялось странным образом? Код я выложил.

Comment: Вероятно, проблема в том, что GetKeyboardLayout возвращает раскладку для текущего потока, которая также может не соответствовать реальной системной раскладке, если окно свернуто. Надо найти фоновый поток активного окна, и его раскладку брать.

Comment: @D.Stark "Как же вы тогда объясните мои наблюдения на счёт нажатия клавиши Shift где её toggled state менялось странным образом?" - грубо говоря, в нем мусор, неинициализированные значения. На них не нужно смотреть.

Comment: Хорошо. С раскладкой я поработаю. А что вы скажете на счёт регистра? Ведь если регистр букв не верен, значит состояния клавиш определены не верно... Что делать с этим?

Comment: Я изменил код получения раскладки так: `GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), out procId))`. Спасибо за совет, всё работает.

Comment: @D.Stark Из-за приведения short в byte у вас старший бит теряется. Нужно не заморачиваться с состоянием всех клавиш, а просто проверять VK_SHIFT (старший бит) и VK_CAPITAL (младший бит), в зависимости от их значений прогонять через ToUpper.

Comment: Хорошо. А вы уверены что на всех существующих раскладках в мире только клавиши LShift, RShift и CapsLock меняют коды символов при вводе? А как же NumLock?

Comment: Я тоже думал о проблеме приведения short к byte. Можно попробовать получить все биты из short и на основе первого и последнего создать byte?

Comment: @D.Stark NumLock обычно переключает между символом и не-символом. Но на счет всех существующих не уверен. Если это важно, то да - наверное надо получать все и преобразовывать short в byte, так чтобы сохранялся старший бит.

Comment: Странно, но toggled state не фиксируется (ну, например, тот же CapsLock - если он будет включён, регистр не изменится; если будет зажат и удерживаться, то как и в случае Shift, всё работает как надо): https://pastebin.com/4GgQ3T0T.

Comment: @D.Stark да, для Caps Lock это не работает. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! А что если нам поступить вот так: https://pastebin.com/fEuDiYPm. Из одной функции брать toggled state, а из другой downup... Работает как нужно да и какую то отдельную клавишу выделять не приходится.

Comment: @D.Stark Да, можно и так.