# Баги при работе с клавиатурными хуками

Tags: c#, winforms, hook, keyboardhook

Есть участок кода где перехватываются клавиши и блокируются:

```
public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
       var objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
       if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin)
       {
          return (IntPtr)1; // <WinKey> 
       }
       else if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Alt || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Tab)
       {
          return (IntPtr)1; // <Alt>+<Tab> 
       }
       else if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Alt || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Space)
       {
          return (IntPtr)1; // <Alt>+<Space> 
       }
       else if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LControlKey || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RControlKey || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LShiftKey || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RShiftKey || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Escape)
       {
           return (IntPtr)1; // <Control>+<Shift>+<Escape> 
       }
       else if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LControlKey || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Alt || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Delete)
       {
          return (IntPtr)1; // <Control>+<Alt>+<Del> 
       }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(this.m_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Почему при таком подходе не все клавиши блокируются?

В Данном случае не блокируется это сочетание клавиш: ( Не видит клавишу Alt )

```
else if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LControlKey || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Alt || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Delete)
{
   MessageBox.Show(objKeyInfo.key.ToString()); // Проверка какая клавиша нажата
   return (IntPtr)1; // <Control>+<Alt>+<Del> 
}
```

Просто для каждой блокировки клавиш выделять отдельный метод с отдельными клавишами для похукивания не айс.

---

Вызов хука - в классе `SetHook():`

```
public IntPtr m_hHook;
public void SetHook()
{
    m_callback = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc;
    m_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
}
```

---

Попробовал так же сделать связку через: vkCode

```
int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
if (Keys.Control == Control.ModifierKeys || Keys.Delete == (Keys)vkCode || Keys.Alt == (Keys)vkCode)
{
   MessageBox.Show(objKeyInfo.key.ToString());
   return (IntPtr)1; // Ctrl + Alt + Delete
}
```

Просто Alt не хочет читать, подскажите почему такой баг возникает?

И есть ли решение данной проблемы?

[**Новая проверка**]

Пробую проверять так:

```
if ((objKeyInfo.flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN) != 0 && vkCode == (uint)Keys.Control && vkCode == (uint)Keys.Delete)
{
  return (IntPtr)1;
}
// или даже так:

if (Keys.Control == Control.ModifierKeys && (objKeyInfo.flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN) != 0 && vkCode == (uint)Keys.Delete)
{
   return (IntPtr)1;
}
```

Но всё ровно не блокируется именно это сочетание клавиш, хочу понять почему такое случается.

P.S: Система Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы не написали правильный код для блокировки этих сочетаний клавиш. Начать с того, что VK для нажатия клавиши ALT в хуке - на самом деле не `Keys.Alt`, а `Keys.LMenu` или `Keys.RMenu`. Но даже если поменять VK на правильный, все равно условие `if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Alt || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Tab)` никак не может соответствовать "блокировать сочетание клавиш Alt+Tab" - вы блокируете вместо этого **любые** нажатия клавиш Alt и Tab!

Правильно это делается так:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KeyboardHookSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static KeyHooker k;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            k = new KeyHooker();
            k.Start();

            Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;
            Console.WriteLine("Hook installed...");
            Application.Run();
        }

        private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            k.Stop();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public uint vkCode;
        public uint scanCode;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }    

    sealed class KeyHooker : IDisposable 
    {
        //объявления типов, констант и функций Windows API
        delegate IntPtr KeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int HC_ACTION = 0;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;        
        const uint LLKHF_ALTDOWN = 0x20;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

        IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        //начинает отслеживание событий клавиатуры
        public void Start()
        {
            if (disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("KeyLogger");
            if (_hookID != IntPtr.Zero) return;

            _hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookCallback, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

            if (_hookID == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(error, "Failed to install hook! Error: " + error.ToString());
            }
        }

        //останавливает отслеживание событий клавиатуры
        public void Stop()
        {
            if (disposed) return;
            if (_hookID == IntPtr.Zero) return;

            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
            _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        //вызывается Windows при нажатии клавиши
        IntPtr KeyboardHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
            {    
                KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT khs = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                uint vkCode = khs.vkCode;                                

                if ((khs.flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN) != 0 && vkCode == (uint)Keys.Tab)
                {                    
                    return (IntPtr)1; //Cancel Alt+Tab
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        bool disposed = false;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (disposed) return;

            Stop();
            disposed = true;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        ~KeyHooker()
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Также следует помнить, что блокировку системных сочетаний клавиш нужно применять с осторожностью. Если полноэкранное приложение блокирует сочетания клавиш Alt+Tab и Ctrl+Alt+Delete, то в случае его зависания система становится полностью неработоспособной - ничего не остается, кроме как перезагружать системник кнопкой Reset.

Comment: Похоже что `ТС` пишет `WinLocker`.

Comment: @ヒミコ Есть и легальные задачи, в которых может понадобиться перехватывать системные сочетания клавиш, например реализация кассового ПО, которое нельзя свернуть ("Киоск").

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, Всё ровно не блокируется сочетание ctrl + alt + delete, или я опять не так проверяю. И ещё подскажите, тогда получается лучше не использовать Keys.Клавиши а определять всё через константы и через них делать проверку? Или это только для определённых клавиш?

Comment: @ヒミコК сожалению Вы не угадали.

Comment: @Luser Для большинства клавиш перечисление Keys дает правильные значения. Я бы сказал, Alt - особый случай. Я не буду давать готовый код для перехвата ctrl + alt + delete, но вся необходимая информация для решения этой задачи есть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, То есть для Control мне нужно использовать `GetAsyncKeyState` ?